# Unnecessary else statements: Is there any disadvantage to using ELSE IF when just IF can be used?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Consider the speed of the following examples (please ignore that this example is completely ridiculous):

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a == b) {
    return pow(a, 2);
  }
  return a*b;
}
```

versus

```
int multiply(int a, int b) {
  if (a == 0 || b == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a == b) {
    return pow(a, 2);
  } else {
    return a*b;
  }
}
```

Obviously, it's not really necessary here, but when I'm working with complex operations, I find it a lot easier to read when formatted as the latter.  Does it take any longer to run in the second configuration?  Will I be sacrificing anything?

Comment: You will have to profile the code. Chances are the compiler understands what you are doing and produces the same assembler code either way.

Comment: Conceptually `if` are evaluated sequentially, `else if` only if previous are `false`..... Probably compiler is smart enough to adjust your code.

Comment: You'd have to look at the code generated by your compiler to be sure (but I'd be at least a little surprised if the generated code was different).

Comment: [In that code, none](https://godbolt.org/g/ttb6Aa). Gathering results into a single retval local and putting a single `return` at the bottom of the function, potentially plenty. Hopefully that's obvious.

Comment: `else if` is not really a thing.  What you are foing is a else followed by an if that is nested inside that else.  It might help you to see the code in the may it would actually be formatted: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df54145f59f2c27c

Comment: @WhozCraig: but there is a slight difference if you compile with gcc 6.3 instead--one version ends up with an extra jump -- it's compiled as `jmp the_other_version`. (Yes, I realize this only happens if you have both in the same file together, so it's irrelevant--but it does show the degree to which the compiler can recognize that these are essentially identical).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Further to that, clang will compile to identical code for both, even if you **do** gather a common retval and have a single `return` in the latter. All goes to show you gotta compile, analyze, and measure.

Comment: This old blog post may be of interest to you: https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2009/08/31/no-else-after-return-considered-harmful/

Comment: I also find the second variation easier to read, and indeed, I typically use that style.  But to the extent that that's what the question is about, it is fundamentally a matter of opinion, and therefore off-topic here.  The two variations have identical control flow with or without `else`, as I think you recognize, so there's no reason to expect a performance difference.  In fact, I'd be surprised to find a compiler that failed to output exactly the same code for these two alternatives.

Comment: closed as opinion-based, when the question is essentially 'which is faster'...

Comment: Not opinion-based. Question has a factual answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Answering's OP question first, then talking about the general case.

Sepcific-to-your-problem Answer: In your case, since you have the return, under each condition, it will break out of the flow-control. In a general case, chaining them, when necessary, is better.

General Answer: Yes, essentially when you're only using if, your program is checking all the conditions, even if one of them was met.

When doing a chain of if,else-if,else, once one of the conditions is met, all the others, in that chain, will be ignored.

Comment: In OPs code there is return if condition is true.

Comment: You're right about the return, but in a general case, without the returns, that's how it would work. I think it's important to state that.

Comment: Answering with the general case first can be misleading.  It's better to answer OP's question first, then follow that with the expansion for the general case.

Comment: You're right, I will edit that out.

Comment: Although this talks about the code presented in the question, it doesn't seem to address the actual question itself.  I see no reason to think that the OP is confused or uncertain about control flow -- at least, the whole question revolves around his explicit recognition that his two variations on the code have the same result.

Comment: _"essentially when you're only using if, your program is checking all the conditions, even if one of them was met."_ That's simply false. The subsequent conditions will not even be evaluated.

Comment: BoundaryImposition, I think you misunderstood it. The program won't evaluate what's under the condition, but it will still check if the condition is true, that's what the statement says.

Comment: The question is about optimization, not flow control.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, no compiler I'm aware of would fail to 
generate the exact same output for both. However, in the general
case:

1. Write for readability and maintainability
2. Profile profile profile
3. Optimize only where you find bottlenecks
4. Test your optimization using more profiling

The fourth part is important, hardware have many surprising 
optimizations builtin, it's not at all intuitive what will
be faster.